# std::copy n elements or to the end

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I would like to copy up to N elements.

```
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt myCopy_n(InputIt first, InputIt last, Size count, OutputIt result)
{
    Size c = count;
    while (first != last && c > 0) {
        *result++ = *first++;
        --c;
    }
    return result;
}
```

is there a way to do this with std functions? I could also:

```
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt myCopy_n(InputIt first, InputIt last, Size count, OutputIt result)
{
    if(std::distance(first, last) > count)
        return std::copy_n(first,count,result);
    return std::copy(first,last,result);
}
```

however, besides being cumbersome, it goes over the range twice (distance, copy). If i'm using a transform iterator, or filter iterator, those are O(N) unnecessary calls to my filter/transform function.

```
template <class InputIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_n_max(InputIt begin, InputIt end, OutputIt last, size_t count)
{
    return std::copy_if(begin, end, last, 
                        [&count](typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::reference)
                        { return count--> 0; });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}), out;
    copy_n_max(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(out), 40);
    for(int i : out) std::cout <<i << " ,";
}
```

outputs  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

however, this will continue until end, and not count times. so still, more unnecessary calls to my filter/transform function...

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: @remyabel It seems pretty specific to me.

Comment: To be honest your first solution seems the most straightforward; call it something like copy_upto_n() and call it a day; It traverses the range just once (least amount of constraints), and it never does more than count dereferences of the input, unlike the third solution. I was actually surprised that copy_n doesn't behave that way in the first place...

Comment: Like @Stefan, I like your `myCopy_n` the most. As it happens, that's pretty much exactly what I suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254075/how-to-read-n-integers-into-a-vector today. Other solutions seem overly complicated and/or overly constrained. KISS.

Comment: @Stefan: `copy_n` *can't* behave that way because it isn't passed an end iterator.

Answer (score 20):

If you have access to the whole data structure, and therefore its size, you can use the following:

```
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
std::copy_n(v2.begin(), std::min(NUM, v2.size()), std::back_inserter(v1));
```

If you have access to only iterators, I don't know how to do this using only std functions without calculating the distance. This is cheap for random-access iterators but duplicates work for other types.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i_begin, i_end, o_begin;
std::copy_n(i_begin, std::min(NUM, std::distance(i_begin, i_end)), o_begin);
```

Comment: yeah, your way is less cumbersome but runtime the same. I'm thinking this is the best we're going to get. will have to copy by myself or pay the price for "distance" if the filter/transform function is negligible. seems a shame that copy_n it's protected by an end iterator.

Comment: @user2232888 The complexity of `std::distance` is constant for random-access iterators. So either `std::distance` is free, or you know the size of the container before hand and [Neil Kirk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2068573/neil-kirk)'s first solution will work.

Comment: Johathan Mee, that's not correct when all you have are iterators. Calling ++ can be expensive if you're using filter/transform iterators...

Comment: @user2232888 If you have only non-random-access iterators and performance is critical, I would use my own function.

Answer (score 8):

I would go for something like this:

```
template <class InputIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_n_max(InputIt begin, InputIt end, OutputIt last, size_t count)
{
    return std::copy_if(begin, 
                        end, 
                        last, 
                        [&count](typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::reference) -> bool 
                        {
                            if (count > 0)
                            {
                                --count;
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        });
}
```

Using `copy_if` predicate to check whether or not enough of this input was copied.
Main advantage I see here is no extra `std::distance` involved.

[Live example on IDEOne](http://ideone.com/x8nwKV)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler will simplify it. And I find it more readable.

Comment: `decltype(*begin)&` => nope, not really. What you want is `typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::reference`, just so that it works with *proxies* (like in `std::vector<bool>`). In C++14, you could also go with `auto&`, and not look back.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I do not understand the problem with `declatype(*begin)&` can you show me an example where it won't work ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sorry, I read too fast (again) :( Thanks for the info, I update everything.

Comment: Won't that consume the entire input iterator?

Comment: @BenJackson Indeed. That will certainly be an issue if iterating is costly.

Comment: @Johan If it's `stdin`, for example, that would be losing data.

Comment: @BenJackson and even an infinite loop, no ?

Answer (score 8):

There's a simple way to use the `std::copy_if`-overload added by C++11 for your task (Only needs InputIterators):

```
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt myCopy_n(InputIt first, InputIt last, Size count, OutputIt result)
{
    return std::copy_if(first, last, result,
        [&](typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::reference)
        {return count && count--;});
}
```

BTW: It gets even better in C++14, no need for a variable or such a complicated argument:

```
std::copy_if(first, last, result,
    [count = some_complicated_expression](auto&&) mutable
    {return count && count--;});
```

Comment: The only annoyance are unnecessary checks when `count` is bigger than the size of the range.

Comment: Well, yes, one could add some template with all the optimizations and shortcuts used in the standard-library. I think an overload for `std::copy_n` should be workable.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ah! I had completely glossed over that fact! Indeed, it's `copy_if` and not `copy_until`.

Comment: why are you returning count && count-- ? why not just count-->0?
I will have to look into this  [count = some_complicated_expression]. does this thing have a name?

Comment: @user2232888 I'm returning that, because I do not know whether count is signed or unsigned. Might even make early return more likely, though don't know. And that's an initializer, needed to use for example move-semantics, and part of C++14.

Comment: You can avoid the complexity in C++11 via `(...)` for your argument list.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: Yes, but then I make a useless copy.

Comment: Any decent compiler will inline the predicate and optimize away the argument-passing completely, don't you think? Let's face it, STL generally requires a decent optimizer at the helm for any sort of efficiency.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: If it can prove that neither copy-ctor nor dtor have any observable behavior, yes it can and should. No guarantee above a certain amount of complexity. Why throw the dice?

Comment: It's an iterator. It better not have a lot of complexity.

Comment: @Stiles: But the predicate gets the pointee of that iterator, however it wants it: As a copied value or by reference.

Comment: The downside of this is that, even though it will do no more copies after `count` reaches zero, it still has to do all the work of incrementing the iterator and comparing it to the end iterator.  Throwing an exception would end the loop early but probably violates the Standard requirements on user-supplied predicates.

Comment: @BenVoigt If incrementing the iterator is complex enough or we disable optimization, sure.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with C++20, this problem is solved nicely by `std::ranges::views::take(e, f)`... it terminates either at the end of the input range `e`, or when `f` elements are iterated, whichever comes first.

Comment: Yes, the new(-er) tools are nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `copy_if` with a custom predicator, and it works for older versions of c++.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


struct LimitTo
{
    LimitTo( const int n_ ) : n(n_)
    {}

    template< typename T >
    bool operator()( const T& )
    {
        return n-->0;
    }

    int n;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > v1{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    std::vector< int > v2;

    std::copy_if( std::begin(v1), std::end(v1), std::back_inserter(v2), LimitTo(3) );

    std::copy( std::begin(v1), std::end(v1), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,", ") );
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::copy( std::begin(v2), std::end(v2), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,", ") );
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This example copies n elements, using predicator `LimitTo`.

Comment: [Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479989/ben-jackson) as the other answers using `copy_if`, it keeps incrementing the iterator after the count has been reached.