# How to read N integers into a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, input

If I want to read *all* integers from standard input to a vector, I can use the handy:

```
vector<int> v{istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator()};
```

But let's assume I only want to read `n` integers. Is the hand-typed loop everything I got?

```
vector<int> v(n);
for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> v[i];
```

Or is there any more right-handed way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::copy n elements or to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119212/stdcopy-n-elements-or-to-the-end)

Answer (score 12):

You usually shouldn't do this with `std::copy_n`, which assumes that the provided iterator, when incremented *n* times, remains valid:

> Copies exactly `count` values from the range beginning at `first` to the range beginning at `result`. Formally, for each non-negative integer `i < n`, performs `*(result + i) = *(first + i)`.
>
> <sup>([cppreference.com article on `std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n))</sup>

If you can guarantee that, then fine, but generally with `std::cin` that's not possible. You can quite easily have it dereferencing an invalid iterator:

> The default-constructed `std::istream_iterator` is known as the end-of-stream iterator. When a valid `std::istream_iterator` reaches the end of the underlying stream, it becomes equal to the end-of-stream iterator. Dereferencing or incrementing it further invokes undefined behavior.
>
> <sup>([cppreference.com article on `std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator))</sup>

You're pretty much there with your loop, though I'd probably use stronger termination condition to avoid excess reads from a "dead" stream:

```
vector<int> v(n);
for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (!cin >> v[i])
       break;
```

I'd be tempted actually to wrap this into something that's like `std::copy_n`, but accepts a full "range" whose bounds may be validated in addition to counting from *0* to *N*.

An implementation might look like:

```
template<class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_atmost_n(InputIt first, InputIt last, Size count, OutputIt result)
{
   for (Size i = 0; i < count && first != last; ++i)
      *result++ = *first++;
   return result;
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
copy_atmost_n(
   std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
   std::istream_iterator<int>(),
   N,
   std::back_inserter(v)
);
```

Now you get *M* elements, where *M* is either the number of inputs provided or *N*, whichever is smaller.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91690e62beb9bedf))

Comment: To confirm I’m interpreting this answer correctly, the issue with `copy_n` is that if the stream encounters a problem before reading n elements, the behavior is undefined? So basically, “if you trust your data source, go for it, but if you don’t, do not use `copy_n`?”

Comment: @templatetypedef Pretty much - and if you "go for it" you save an iterator comparison on each step I suppose. But for general usage I'm going to use `copy_atmost_n` from hereon tbh

Comment: @templatetypedef Note that I'm thinking of EOF specifically - tbh I'm not sure what happens if there's data but read/parse fails

Answer (score 11):

As given in comments, `copy_n` is unsafe for this job, but you can use `copy_if` with mutable lambda:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    const int N = 10;
    std::vector<int> v;
    //optionally v.reserve(N);
    std::copy_if(
        std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
        std::back_inserter(v), 
        [count=N] (int)  mutable {
            return count && count--;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

as pointed out in this answer:
[std::copy n elements or to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119212/stdcopy-n-elements-or-to-the-end)

Comment: Wouldn't it cause UB if there is not enough input provided?

Comment: You can't fix it. `std::copy_n` is not fit for this task.

Comment: Still no. Dereferencing the `std::istream_iterator` "end iterator" has UB, not throw semantics. (See my answer)

Comment: @bartop I suggest removing the `copy_n` part and just leave _As given in comments, copy_n is unsafe, but you can use copy_if with mutable lambda:_ followed by your nice solution.

Comment: The version with `copy_if` is better (downvote removed). _Technically_ there's no guarantee the predicate will be called "in order", but we are guaranteed it will be called exactly _<last-first>_ times and there's no good practical reason to call it out of order. So this should work. Still, a wrapper like my `copy_atmost_n` is terser, more expressive, and easier to get right.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, I think I have better idea.