# Can the reading of N input values be made more elegant with C++20?

Tags: c++, input, c++20, idioms, std-ranges

Suppose I want to read n integers from the standard input stream. Reading:

[How to read N integers into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54254075/1593077)

I find the recommended solution is basically:

```
template<class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_atmost_n(InputIt first, InputIt last, Size count, OutputIt result)
{
   for (Size i = 0; i < count && first != last; ++i)
      *result++ = *first++;
   return result;
}

auto read_n(std::istream& is, std::size_t n) {
    vector<int> result;
    // possibly reserve n elements
    copy_atmost_n(
       std::istream_iterator<int>(is),
       std::istream_iterator<int>(),
       n,
       std::back_inserter(result)
    );
    return result;
}
```

I dislike this for the following reasons:

1. The use of `copy_atmost_n()` is making an assumption regarding how failure to "dereference" the `first` iterator will effect `first`'s subsequent value. But this assumed behavior is more idiosyncratic than universally obvious. I'm sure this would confuse lots of developers.
2. A "staging" variable is needed.
3. Repetition of `std::istream_iterator<int>`.

Does C++20, and especially ranges, afford us a nicer approach?

Note: It is not absolutely necessary to return an `std::vector<int>`. Some kind of lazy structure may also be used if it makes things easier.

Comment: @PasserBy: Sorry, I mis-copy-pasted. As for "why not iterate and assign?": 1. I don't want my code to be so imperative. 2. I adopt (a relxation of) [Sean Parent's approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA), that writing a raw loop is a big deal, not be done lightly, and very often can and should be avoided.

Comment: *an assumption regarding how failure to "dereference" the first iterator will effect first's subsequent value* What do you mean by that? `copy_atmost_n` uses generalized iterator semantics, if you got some iterators that can't be used that way then they are broken, right? What sort of a failure you have in mind, and how would that failure interact with typical iterator contracts?

Comment: @UnslanderMonica: I don't believe that it does. That is, it seems to assume that if only less than n elements can be read, than the iterator will become equal to last.

Comment: @Barry: It implicitly assumes that, and more explicitly assumes either an exception or being equal to last. Otherwise - infinite loop I guess.

Comment: @einpoklum Well, yes, that's how iterators are supposed to work. If that isn't true, you don't really have iterators. None of the algorithms will work.

Comment: @einpoklum *it seems to assume that if only less than n elements can be read, than the iterator will become equal to last* - the contract it expects of a forward iterator stipulates that it's valid as long as it's not equal to some other iterator suitable for the purpose of such determination. Then it's up to the caller to provide such suitable iterator, so if anything, it's the caller (`read_n`) making such assumptions. There's no other generic way of determining an invalid iterator than comparing it to one suitable for that purpose. That's the only mechanism you have.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica: You're right about `read_n` making the assumption.

Comment: @Barry: It is not obvious that an iterator over some kind of streamed input would change into some fixed `last` if it fails to advance. I suppose you could language-lawyer me and say that then it's not a real iterator, but it would be news to me and not something intuitive.

Comment: *It is not obvious that an iterator over some kind of streamed input would change into some fixed last if it fails to advance* It may not be obvious, but that's what the standard says about stream iterators' behavior, AFAIK.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica: That's what the standard says about an `std::istream` iterator, you mean? ... but not everything is an `std::istream`.

Comment: The way that every iterator-pair algorithm works is that it assumes that `[first, last)` is a valid range, which means you can iterator and dereference `first` until `first == last` is true. If you had some type such that `first != last` but `*first` was nevertheless invalid for some reason, that would be impossible to use in any algorithm. It's very much the contract of the iterator model in C++.

Comment: Otherwise, even something as basic as `copy(first, last, back_inserter(v))` would be undefined behavior. How else would the algorithm know how to stop copying? The iterator-pair is its only input.

Answer (score 3):

The answer *should*<sup>†</sup> be:

```cpp
auto read_n(std::istream& is, std::size_t n) {
    return std::ranges::istream_view<int>(is) | std::views::take(n);
}
```

if you just want a lazy range. And then collecting that eagerly into a `vector<int>` as you see fit.

---

<sup>†</sup>But that doesn't quite work yet due to [LWG 3408](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3408), but should be resolved soon by [P2259](https://wg21.link/p2259), so it will eventually be correct.

Comment: As you know... links instead of brief descriptions are frowned upon. So, can you briefly describe the problem?

Comment: @einpoklum No, I can't _briefly_ describe the problem. If you're interested, you can read the links. If you're not interested, it's enough to know that the code doesn't compile today due to a library bug but will compile soon.